# Where is the file? file:///home/

Tags: path, directory, filesystems

I am searching for a file and the file path looks like "file:///home/".
3 slashes in a row?? What does that mean? May someone can help me.

Regards,
Realer

Comment: That could be an interesting thread for you: [here](https://superuser.com/questions/352133/why-do-file-urls-start-with-3-slashes)

Answer (score 1):

The complete syntax is file://host/path.

If the host is localhost, it can be omitted, resulting in file:///path.